# Visual Basic 6 obtener datos desde TXT con formate Excel

Tags: vba, vb6

estoy trabajando con Vb 6, tengo un archivo TXT que tiene filas y columnas como una planilla de Excel, solo que las columnas están delimitadas por "," y no tengo identificada los números de las filas.

Los que necesito es recuperar un valor de la ultima linea de este TXT en la posición 2
el formato de la ultima linea es:

ZZ,Actualización realizada el: 28/10/2016 a las:,0.00,0.00,,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0,-1.00,0,-1,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,,,,

El datos que necesito es "actualizacion realizada..." es para reemplazar por un numero y ahi validar la fecha de creacion de dicho archivo

Comparto parte del codigo donde se realiza la carga del archivo ya que es en ese momento que se necesita hacer la validacion de la fecha de creacion:

```
> Public Sub getXLS_ADO(path As String)
> 
> 
> 
> Dim i, y, x As Integer Dim linea, aux As String Dim cmdIns As String
> Dim lineatext As String Dim totalFila As Integer
> 
> If Dir(path) <> "" Then
> 
> Open path For Input As #1
> 
> x = FilaInicial y = ColumnaInicial i = 0
> 
> 
> ' Inicializo la tabla previa 'cn.Execute "delete from TablaPrevia "
> Line Input #1, lineatext ' linea cabecera  Do While Not EOF(1)
>  
>  
>     Line Input #1, lineatext
>       
>     linea = formatear(esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 1), " "), " ", CodLengh)
>     aux = formatear(esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 1), " "), " ", CodLengh)
>     linea = linea + " - " + Mid(esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 2), " "), 1, DescLengh) '    linea = linea + " - " +
> formatear(esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 2), " "), " ", DescLengh) '  
> linea = linea + " - " + formatear(esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 3),
> 0), " ", ImpLengh)
>     frmReporte.lstListos.AddItem linea
>          
>     ' Agrego al Vector Orgigen
>     Origen(i).cod = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 1), " ")
>     Origen(i).Desc = esNulo(eliminar_caracteres(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 2)), " ")
>     Origen(i).Precio = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 3), 0)
>     Origen(i).PrecioCont = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 4), 0)
>     Origen(i).Pais = esNulo(eliminar_caracteres(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 5)), " ")
>     Origen(i).GL1 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 6), 0)
>     Origen(i).GL2 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 7), 0)
>     Origen(i).GL3 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 8), 0)
>     Origen(i).GL4 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 9), 0)
>     Origen(i).GLR = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 10), 0)
>     Origen(i).GC1 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 11), 0)
>     Origen(i).GC2 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 12), 0)
>     Origen(i).GC3 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 13), 0)
>     Origen(i).GC4 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 14), 0)
>     Origen(i).GCR = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 15), 0)
>     Origen(i).PuntosTCL = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 16), 0)
>     Origen(i).PuntosTCC = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 17), 0)
>     Origen(i).Cuotas = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 18), 0)
>     Origen(i).Tasa = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 19), 0)
>     Origen(i).Oferta = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 20), 0)
>     Origen(i).Entrega = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 21), 0)
>     Origen(i).PrecioTar = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 22), 0)
>     Origen(i).GT1 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 23), 0)
>     Origen(i).GT2 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 24), 0)
>     Origen(i).GT3 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 25), 0)
>     Origen(i).GT4 = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 26), 0)
>     Origen(i).GTR = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 27), 0)
>     Origen(i).PuntosTCT = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 28), 0)
>     Origen(i).CuotasClasif = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 29), 0)
>     Origen(i).TasaClasif = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 30), 0)
>     Origen(i).OfertaClasif = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 31), 0)
>     Origen(i).EntregaClasif = esNulo(ObtenerCampo(lineatext, 32), 0)
> 
>     'agregarLineaBD cmdIns
>     i = i + 1 Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé si te he entendido del todo. Si conoces la última línea del fichero y el formato es siempre el mismo "ZZ,...." cuando proceses esa línea extraes el contenido con la función Mid() que te permite indicar en qué carácter comenzar a extraer datos y cuantos caracteres extraes.

```
Mid(MyString, 1, 3) 'Comienza a extraer desde el caracter 1 y extrae 3 caracteres.
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el componente llamado "Microsoft Rich textBox Control" y cargar el TXT en este componente, luego tienes que usar la función "find"

-Agrega un botón y el control mencionado.
EJEMPLO.

```
Option Explicit
Dim temp1
dim qbuscar 
dim qrempla

Private Sub Command1_Click()
RichTextBox1.LoadFile "C:\nobredetuarchivo.txt"
qbuscar = "texto a buscar"
qrempla = "Texto a remplazar" 
temp1 = RichTextBox1.Find(qbuscar, 0, Len(Me.RichTextBox1.Text))

If temp1 = "-1" Then
MsgBox "no encontrado..."
Exit Sub
End If

RichTextBox1.SelStart = temp1
RichTextBox1.SelLength = len(qbuscar) 
RichTextBox1.SelText = qrempla

RichTextBox1.SaveFile "C:\nobredetuarchivo.txt", rtfText
MsgBox "Remplazado con exito!"

End Sub
```